# How do I sort whatsapp media files according to sender

Tags: media-files

Is it possible to sort out whatsapp media files with the name of the sender?

Answer (score 1):

By copying the photos to your computer you can sort it by different exif details like camera taken, date, location etc. So try cleaning and organizing by that. you can copy back the needed photos to your mobile later. Hope it helps.

But as far as I know, there'sno such option.